# How to move files with metadata in SharePoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have written some code that copies files and their metadata to a new URL.  But for some reason it's only copying metadata for Word and Excel files.  Anything non-microsoft, like PDFs do not get their metadata copied.  My code is below, does anyone see anything I should change?

Also, this code worked for PDFs when it ran under 2007...

```
static void CopyFileWithHistoryCrossSite(SPFile sourceFile, SPFolder destination, string destinationUrl)
{
    byte[] binFile;

    binFile = sourceFile.OpenBinary();

    destination.Files.Add(destinationUrl, binFile, true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will not "copy metadata" in destination, the metadata will be recreated based on the stream of the file's stream (it is called "property promotion", see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979617.aspx).

Try SPFile.CopyTo/MoveTo as I think they may copy metadata.

Comment: I also saw that a few of the many SPFileCollection.Add methods allows you to pass a HashTable that contains MetaData, should I consider rewriting my function to use this?

Comment: I did not use them, but based on descriptions these versions of Add should allow you to copy metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this discussion on SO: [When is SPFile.Properties != to SPFile.Item.Properties in SharePoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388502/when-is-spfile-properties-to-spfile-item-properties-in-sharepoint)