# Difference between SPFile.Property and SPFile.Item?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have this code (`f` is a SPFile object):

```
    f.Properties["Publish"] = 0;
    //f.Properties["PublishedDate"] = DateTime.Now;
    f.Update();
```

If I run this it updates my Publish meta data.  If I uncomment the date line it will error out with a type mismatch.

If I use this code:

```
    f.Item["Publish"] = 0;
    f.Item["PublishedDate"] = DateTime.Now;
    f.Item.Update();
```

Everything updates as expected.  What is the difference between these two methods?  Why do they *almost* do the same thing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is SPFile.Properties != to SPFile.Item.Properties in SharePoint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388502/when-is-spfile-properties-to-spfile-item-properties-in-sharepoint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have a look at a similar question I asked some time ago [When is SPFile.Properties != to SPFile.Item.Properties in SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388502/when-is-spfile-properties-to-spfile-item-properties-in-sharepoint)?